# Why does my encrypted string looks like consisting of only question marks?

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding

I'm encrypting a string in Java, and when I'm printing the encrypted data, I see only question marks.

As an example:

- Plain text: `jjkkjlkljkj`
- Encrypted text: `???????????`
- After decrypting this text again, I'm getting `jjkkjlkljkj` again.

So it looks like the encryption worked right. But why can I see only question marks?

Comment: Whilst we get what you mean - your question needs to be a little clearer and a little time to format it nicely is worth it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's because you can't print the strings that are resulting from the encryption.

Note that saving the encrypted result in a string will possibly result in *loss* of the data, so don't do that. Take it as a byte array, and convert it to a displayable format, like [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) or just simple Hex.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is the way how you presented the encrypted data. The character encoding used doesn't recognize those characters as one of its charset, nor does it have a suitable glyph (font) for those characters. Even then, when you used the "correct" character encoding (try to display it with UTF-8) it would not have been human readable.

I suppose that you have it in flavor of a `byte[]` and are trying to convert it to `String` using `new String(bytearray)`. If your purpose is to transfer it as a `String` instead of a `byte[]`, then you should rather use either [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) [`Base64#encodeBase64String()`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte[]%29) or to convert the `byte[]` to a hexstring like follows:

```
StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(bytea.length * 2);
for (byte b : bytea) {
    if ((b & 0xff) < 0x10) hex.append("0");
    hex.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
String hexString = hex.toString();
```